# How to update the image in tkinter class by key event binding?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

How to display the next image and previous image when the right arrow or left arrow key is pressed? I have done this in a simple example when I don't define the `Example` class but failed when I want to do it in the example code below. I have defined two static methods inside the `Example` class to bind the left arrow and right arrow to the GUI. It works well in printing the event but I don't know how to update the `image` option of the label by `configure(image = next_photo)` and `configure(image = previous_photo)`.
Here is a part of my code:

```
current = 0
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.bind('<Left>', self.left_key)
        self.master.bind('<Right>', self.right_key)
        image = Image.open(image_list[0])
        image = image.resize((800, 600),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        self.logo = tk.Label(self, text="Logo", background="orange")
        self.logo2 = tk.Label(self, image = photo)
        ############################################# ScrolledText ##########################################
        self.edit_space = tkst.ScrolledText(
                master = self,
                wrap   = 'word',  # wrap text at full words only
                width  = 50,      # characters
                height = 10,      # text lines
                bg='beige'        # background color of edit area
        )
        self.other1 = tk.Label(self, background="purple")
        self.other2 = tk.Label(self, background="yellow")
        self.other3 = tk.Label(self, background="pink")
        self.other4 = tk.Label(self, background="gray")
        self.main = tk.Frame(self, background="blue")
        self.logo.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.logo2.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.other1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.other2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.other3.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
        self.other4.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.edit_space.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.main.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=6)
        for row in range(8):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)
        for col in range(3):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)
    @staticmethod
    def left_key(event):
        print(str(event) + " key pressed")
        global current, image_list
        if not (0 <= current + 1 < len(image_list)):
            print("This is the first image")
            return
        current += 1
        image = Image.open(image_list[current])
        image = image.resize((800, 600),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        # self.logo2 = tk.Label(self, image = photo)
        #self.logo2.configure(image = photo)
    @staticmethod
    def right_key(event):
        print(str(event) + " key pressed")
        global current, image_list
        if not (0 <= current - 1 < len(image_list)):
            print("This is the last image")
            return
        current -= 1
        image = Image.open(image_list[current])
        image = image.resize((800, 600),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        # self.logo2 = tk.Label(self, image = photo)
        #self.logo2.configure(image = photo)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.geometry("800x400")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to `bind()` the keystrokes to an event handler (like those static methods). Here's some [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/binding-levels.html).

Comment: @martineau It works when I bind the keystroke to the event handler outside the `Example` class. My problem is to pass the `self` object to the static method within the `Example` class.

Comment: I don't understand—can't you `bind()` the `Example.left_key` and `Example.right_key` methods? They don't need a `self` argument since they're `staticmethod`s.

Comment: @martineau It's binded and I can print the event `print("This is the last image")`. How to bind `photo` to `self.logo2`? (this line of code: `#self.logo2.configure(image = photo)`)

Comment: Since you want to access `self` in those functions, you will need to make them normal non`staticmethod` and add an initial `self` parameter. If you had a wee-bit more code in your question, where it was actually runnable, I'd post a real answer, but you haven't, so for now all I can do is try to explain what to do here in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you create local variable `photo` inside `__init__()` and use it as the image of `logo2`.  However `photo` will be destroyed after `__init__()` is executed which will cause no image is displayed.

In order to fix the problem:

- use `self.photo` instead of `photo`
- change the 2 static methods, `left_key()` and `right_key()`, to instance methods
- set the image of `logo2` inside `left_key()` and `right_key()`: `self.logo2.configure(image=self.photo)`

Furthermore, the checking of the value of `current` inside `left_key()` and `right_key()` may cause problem:

- in `left_key()`, `current > 0` should be checked
- in `right_key()`, `current < len(image_list)-1` should be checked

and the adjustment of `current` in these 2 methods is in wrong direction:

- `left_key()` should decrease `current`
- `right_key()` should increase `current`

Comment: The events are bonded to`master` frame and instance methods doesn't has  the frame attributes. I'm getting this error after changes were made: `self.logo2.configure(image=self.photo)
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'logo2'`

Comment: You have to redefine the two functions as `def left_key(self, event)` and `def right_key(self, event)` if you change them to instance methods.

Comment: You're right. I didn't keep the sequence. It was `def left_key(event, self)`